# Probability of a weighted die

Tags: probability

A die has faces $1$ to $6$ and is weighted so that the probability of throwing $n$ in a single throw is proportional to $n$ $(n=1,2,3,4,5,6)$; that is, equals $λn$; for some constant $\lambda$.

I need to find what $λ$ is, the probability of throwing an even number and the probability of throwing a number greater than $3$.

I think I understand how to find $λ$, it would just be $1$/sum of the $n$'s, so $1/21$.
But how do I get the probability of throwing an even number and the probability of throwing a number greater than $3$ from this?

Would I just sum up the even no's(i.e. $2+4+6=12$), so the probability is $12/21$?
Similarly for no's greater than $3$, which summed up would be ($4+5+6=15$), so the probability is $15/21$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: How would you compute those probabilities with a fair die?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. This is due to the fact that each event (getting $2$ or $4$ or $6$) are **mutually exclusive** events. Hence when you have to find the probability of the union of these events, the addition rule of probability applies.

$$P(\text {even no.})=P(2)+P(4)+P(6)= \frac {12}{21}$$
$$P(\text n \gt 3)=P(4)+P(5)+P(6)= \frac {15}{21}$$